# Button links on Wordpress front page are not clickable

Tags: css, wordpress, html, z-index

I was given a Wordpress theme to install for a new website and then asked to make some customizations.

The site is here:  http://centergrovepto.org/townsend/ (I'm not sure where the original theme came from.)

There are 3 buttons along the right side of the front page slider. "Employers", "Candidates", and "Open Positions".  The buttons were initially clickable and all they did was change the current slider image.

I'm trying to make them clickable so that they open the corresponding page.  If you hover over each button you can see in the status bar that the link paths are setup correctly, but when I click the button nothing happens.

I'm guessing it is a CSS issue and some layer is covering up the actual buttons, but I don't know enough CSS to figure out what the cause is.  I have the Firebug plugin for Firefox installed so I can more easily inspect the CSS.  I've played around with changing the z-index of various elements, but I just can't get it to work.

Comment: Let me know if it works or not

Comment: did you try [adding a target](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10338514/599402)?

Comment: Your z-indexing looks fine. I'm not seeing any cursor:pointer declarations for any of the related elements, so your <a> links are most definitely on top since the cursor becomes a pointer. I've placed an answer bringing your attention to your jQuery Faded plugin, but also check if anywhere else is targeting those elements and setting "e.preventDefault" or "return false" within the click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually think it's your jQuery Faded plugin. It looks as if this:

```
if (o.pagination) {
    if (o.autopagination) {
        $t.append("<ul class="+o.pagination+"></ul>");
        $c.children().each(function(){
            $("."+o.pagination+"",$t).append("<li><a rel="+number+" href=\"#\" >"+(number+1)+"</a></li>");
            number++;
        });
    }
    $("."+o.pagination+" li a:eq(0)",$t).parent().addClass("current");
    $("."+o.pagination+" li a",$t).click(function(){
        current = $("."+o.pagination+" li.current a",$t).attr("rel");                                   
        clicked = $(this).attr("rel");
        if (current != clicked) {animate("pagination",clicked,current);}
        if(o.autoplay){pause();}
        return false; //THIS LINE PREVENTS DEFAULT ACTION WHEN <a> LINK IS CLICKED
    });
}
```

Is preventing the default action of your links. I'm not sure what will happen, but try commenting the "return false" line out. See if any unwanted side-effects happen. Otherwise, add this code to your (or what I assume is yours) custom.js file:

```
jQuery(".pagination ul li a").click(function()
{
    window.location = this.href; //UPDATED FOR EPHRAIM
});
```

Comment: ah [jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/156722)... It's always [jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/156722)... :D

Comment: Personally, I hate trying to solve any kind of issue with jQuery. Yucky stuff.

Comment: This fixed it. I made it return true and it seems to be working. Thanks.

Comment: Very cool. Glad I could help. Please accept this as the answer so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

as I've seen on your site, the 3 buttons are linked like this:

a href="/townsend/employers/"

But i think it should be like this to work because `a href="/townsend/employers/"` does not refer to anywhere in your server

try changing it like so:

```
<a href="http://centergrovepto.org/townsend/employers/">
```

Comment: no, that's not the problem, because if you open it in a new tag, it works

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why this is happining, because if you open the link in a new tab, it works perfectly. It's possible that it's a css problem, but more likely, it has to do with your HTML.

What I would try is adding a target to your link. This will tell it to open the link specifically in the window your in, which may solve the problem. (I haven't tested it myself though)

Instead of

```
<a href="/townsend/employers/"></a>
```

Try changing it to one of the following:

```
<a href="/townsend/employers/" target="_parent"></a>
```

Or, if that one doesn't work, try this one as well

```
<a href="/townsend/employers/" target="_self"></a>
```

Let me know if that helps!